# How to auto close angular modal if there is no interaction for a while

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular modal in my SPA which allow user for filtering the applications on certain criteria. I want to close the popup filter modal if user does not do any interaction for 15 sec.

If I use $timeout as below:

```
$timeout(function () {
                $modalInstance.close();
            }, 15000)
```

It closes the modal after 15 sec since it is open regardless of user interaction.

Does angular has any library function to do so, if not How we can achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but it is either off-topic (SO is not for recommending libraries) or too-broad (what constitutes "user interaction"?)

Comment: Use the return value of `$timeout`, eg `var timer = $timeout(...)` to cancel / restart the timeout if you detect user interaction via `$timeout.cancel(timer)`

Comment: @Phil, I think the OP is asking about *how* to detect user interaction... I think

Comment: @NewDev that's why it's a comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: @Phil, now I'm thinking that you might be right. "regardless of user interaction" could mean "I detected user interaction but can't stop the timeout" :)

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your response I think it is directional way to do it. I will try to handle the click event on modal and cancel the time everytime

Comment: @NewDev my intention of asking question was to find out the way of closing a modal if there is no interaction by end user. I know how to detect user interaction, sorry for the wrong formation of sentence.

Comment: Yes, there is ng-idle https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle Does exactly what you want.